# Can't tick to checkbox using Selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to build a script to auto-submit my application with Selenium and write it in Python. When I go to the accept terms and conditions, it requires me to tick a checkbox. I tried to locate the element by code

```
terms = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//input[@id='_2a0ba0a0a0e0a0a0a5a1a_input']")
terms1.click()
```

but it returns

> Unable to locate element.

Here is the HTML struct I tried.
[DevTool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/newWQ.png)

I tried to wait 60 seconds for the page to load but it didn't work. Does anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to load page elemnts. the checkbox is loaded successfully.

There is two ideas:

1. `copy full XPath` from browser (instead of `copy XPath`) and paste it as the value in your code
   in inspect elements menu, Right click on the element html code, in the menu click on `Copy`, then click on `Copy full XPath`
   `terms = browser.find_element(By.ID, value=The_full_Xpath)`
2. `value="//input[@id='_2a0ba0a0a0e0a0a0a5a1a_input']"` looks like an ID.
   change `By.XPATH` to `By.ID`
   then pass the id as value
   `terms = browser.find_element(By.ID, value="_2a0ba0a0a0e0a0a0a5a1a_input")`

Comment: I tried it but not luck, maybe the website have a security Mechanism prevent auto tool